# Showing last added element in time range object (HTML5 Video related)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

There is a function in HTML5 that shows you the range of buffered time ranges in a video. I want to show the last added 'buffered' section, but this is proving to be quite difficult.

Basically when you click on a time in a video (lets say 00:16), the video begins to buffer if its not already. So we end up with a buffer that goes like 16s-18s, then 16s-20s, etc as the video loads. Now lets say we click somewhere else before that in the video where it is not buffered. So I click on 00:05. The 'buffered' array will have 16-20s and 5s-6s or however much is loaded.

HOWEVER, the 5s-6s will be added BEFORE the 16s-20s in the time range array. That means that we can't just select the last element of an array as the newest buffered section, rather we have to select the first element. Then if you click somewhere else before the 5s mark you end  up with the first part of the array being a different value. Since they are added in this fashion I can't find the latest buffer section added.

What is the best way to go about finding this?

Comment: One of the problems with this is that the timeRanges merge together given enough time. For example, when you seek to 5s, the number of ranges in the buffer goes up to 2. Soon, when this range extends from 5s to 16s, it is removed, so you're back to just one entry in the buffered ranges array.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this would be to make a copy of the `TimeRanges` object in the `buffer` property every time something new is added to the buffer. You can then use this "history" to find the order in which time ranges were added.

For example, with jQuery:

```
var history = [];
$(yourvideo).on("seeked",function(){
    history.push(jQuery.extend({}, this.buffered));
});
```

Comment: How would I go about accessing this data for use? I keep getting objects returned.

Comment: @Johnny Do you want to retrieve the last point in the video seeked to?

Comment: Well, no, because I need the buffered time too. I was just wondering how I go about accessing the data in the array, i.e. do I just have to do history[0] to access the object or something different?

Comment: @Johnny But there is no buffered time just when the event fires. When you click in a new location, the length of video buffered is zero.

Comment: @Johnny Also, that isn't an array, so you can't access the objects in it. You can only get the start and end time of the nth buffered range using `.buffered.start(n)` and `.buffered.end(n)`

Comment: Not necessarily, if you click in an area that has been buffered the buffered length is not 0.

Comment: @Johnny Yes, but I thought you were trying to capture clicks in new areas (as in, not previously buffered). If you click in an area that has already been buffered, nothing is added to the `.buffered` object. Perhaps this would be easier if you explain the problem you are trying to solve; what do you need to use the last range added to the buffer for?